# How to open multiple instances of Mathematica in Mac?

Tags: mac-os-x

In Mac, when I click on the Mathematica icon on the docker, or open Mathematica through Spotlight or the Launcher, I get to the same window that I had already opened.

I need to start a *new* Mathematica session. How do I do it?

Comment: Have a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/312439/open-two-instances-of-the-same-app-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Would opening a new notebook (`⌘N`) and giving it it's own math kernel (look in the Evaluation menu) be sufficient? It will allow you run multiple notebook with their own kernels simultaneously.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli True, it's a solution. Thanks. I think both comments provide the answer I am looking for.